# Take a picture in HoloLens Vuforia Application

Tags: vuforia, hololens

Usually on the HoloLens you can take mixed reality captures by saying "Hey Cortana, take a picture", using the device portal or by pressing both volume buttons simultaneously. This also seems to work by default in self-written applications without adding any code.

However, as soon **as I use Vuforia within my HoloLens application, taking a picture fails**. I guess this is due to Vuforia blocking the camera for other threads. Videos however work fine. Livestreaming via the Device Portal also fails.

What I did was to take a video and extract single frames, however, the quality of the images in this approach is bad compared to real pictures.

**Has anyone found a workaround to take mixed reality pictures within Vuforia Apps?**

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but one of the things you could probably do is create like a voice command that will stop the app from using Vuforia, so that you will be able to use the camera on HoloLens again.

Comment: but then I guess there would be no augmentations anymore since the image targets are not recognized

Comment: I believe you could make the model stay after you recognize it via Vuforia

Comment: Ok, yeah I could probably store it in between. Thanks for the suggestion. However, would still be nice if vuforia could support this.

Comment: Yep, that would be absolutely nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try turning off the camera from vuforia in script. This will allow you to take pictures, but will temporarily stop your app from tracking any objects.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to take a picture in Unity 5.5 and Vuforia 6 and did use

```
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();
```

to turn off tracking and

```
CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
```

to turn off the camera. After that, I was able to take pictures and videos with my holograms.

Currently I am using a simple voice command to enable taking of pictures

```
keywords.Add("Prepare for pictures", () =>
{
    TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();
    CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
});
```